# Defining a html5 data attribute in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I'm trying to declare a Html.Radio button in my mvc app and want to output a data- attribute. Problem is c# does like "-"

```
<%= Html.RadioButton("defaultRadioButton", d.Link, d.IsDefault, new { data-link = d.Link })%>
```

Is there anyway to get round this other than outputting the html myself or creating a helper?

Thanks..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this is ASP.NET MVC 3:

```
<%= Html.RadioButton(
    "defaultRadioButton", 
    d.Link, 
    d.IsDefault, 
    new { 
        data_link = d.Link 
    }
)%>
```

and the underscore will be automatically converted into a dash by the helper.

In previous versions of MVC an ugly hack could be appiled:

```
<%= Html.RadioButton(
    "defaultRadioButton", 
    d.Link, 
    d.IsDefault, 
    new Dictionary<string, object> { 
        { "data-link", d.Link } 
    }
) %>
```

Comment: Ahh I thought I'd seen it like that somewhere. Unfortunatley we haven't moved to 3 yet. Although we may be doing so soon.

Comment: @mjmcloug, OK, see the ugly hack then.

Comment: @mjmcloug, a custom HTML helper could save you from the burden of this ugliness. Also wishing you a soon migration to MVC 3.

Comment: I'll have to see if how often this crops up before creating a custom helper... No point doing so if this is the only case and we do migrate soon. Thanks